# Obtain s3 bucket information from s3_resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, resources, bucket, sts

I have a python program to obtain aws s3 bucket information from boto3.client:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.list_buckets() # get bucket list
bucket_location = s3_client.get_bucket_location # get bucket region
log_location = s3_client.get_bucket_logging # get bucket access log location
inventory_location = s3_client.list_bucket_inventory_configurations # get bucket inventory location
```

I want to get same information under another account. Here's to code to assume_role:

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
sts_credentials = sts_client.assume_role(
  RoleArn="<another_role>",
  RoleSessionName="<session_name>"
)
credentials = sts_credentials['Credentials']
s3_resource = boto3.resource(
  's3', 
  aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'], 
  aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'], 
  aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken']
)
```

The s3_resource is created successfully, 2 options come into my mind to continue but not sure which one is feasible:

1. Use boto3.client equallent api in boto3.resource.
2. Create boto3.client from boto3.resource then extract information in the same way.

Would anyone share the solution? Thanks!

Comment: I can get bucket list and logging from boto3.resource:      s3_resource.buckets.all() 
      s3_resource.BucketLogging(<bucket_name>)
      But still struggle in figout out region and inventory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a new client:

```py
import boto3

credentials = boto3.client('sts').assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::0000000000000000:role/custom-role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)['Credentials']
    
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken']
)
s3_client = session.client('s3')
response = s3_client.list_buckets() # get bucket list
```